# Como retornar o resultado de uma consulta no InfluxDB com a coluna "time" como número

Tags: banco-de-dados, influxdb

Estou fazendo testes no InfluxDB (dentro de um container docker) e, para tal eu executei o código abaixo:

```
# criando a imagem do influxdb
docker run -d --name influxdb -p 8086:8086 influxdb

# acessando o terminal dentro da imagem
docker exec -it influxdb sh

# dentro do terminal no container, eu acesso o CLI do influx
influx

# crio o banco de dados de testes
> create database test

# defino o banco de testes como padrão
> use test

# crio a tabela "foo" e insiro uma coluna "bar" com valor "123"
> insert foo bar=123

# seleciono tudo na tabela "foo" para verificar se foi inserido
> select * from foo

# resultado da seleção
name: foo
time                bar
----                ---
1583928133832191101 123
```

A partir desse exemplo e, conforme a [documentação do InfluxDB](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/spec/) eu posso retornar o resultado da query a partir do navegador acessando a url `http://localhost:8086/query?db=test&q=select%20*%20from%20foo` mas, ao fazê-lo, o resultado retornado traz a coluna time com uma formatação diferente:

```js
{
    "results": [
        {
            "statement_id":0,
            "series": [
                {
                    "name": "foo",
                    "columns": [
                        "time",
                        "bar"
                    ],
                    "values":[
                        [
                            "2020-03-11T12:02:13.832191101Z",
                            123
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Se eu preciso da propriedade time no formato original pra que seja possível fazer um update no registro, o que preciso fazer para que, ao acessar esse dado através do protocolo HTTP, a coluna "time" seja retornada sem formatação?

Answer (score 1):

Logo após postar a pergunta eu encontrei a solução na documentação. Segundo ela, eu posso passar o parâmetro "epoch=ns" para que a coluna "time" não seja formatada, assim:

`http://localhost:8086/query?`**`epoch=ns`**`&db=test&q=select%20*%20from%20foo`